# accessing a network from afuer with 3g modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have to access a network in a very distant and remote place where I only have good access to 3g .. the problem here is that I have a TL-MR3220 router and a modem ZTE MF180 3g and want Internet access atra time I saw the router can put my account no-ip.org not struggle with dynamic IP provider direcion

Comment: This is difficult to read.  Can you put more punctuation and capitalize your sentences and maybe reword the last sentence to be more specific?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean for "have to access"? I think, you have to access to a web server, or another machine on the local remote lan via the tl-mr!
1) the router and the modem are compatible? do you can connect to internet?
2) the provider assign you a public ip address?
3) configure port forwarding as your requirement

Comment: if the router and modem are supported on the public IP with no-ip service is not solved ?? and ports do not think it is necessary ... it is to have access to a computer on the LAN

Comment: the public ip is only one requirement , if you have public ip on the lan too, yes you may connect to your computer form outside the network, but as usual , your ip address on the lan is a private ip (192.168.x.x - 10.x.x.x - 172.16.x.x) you must enable port forwarding to tell the router when someone try to connect a public port , at which computer he must forward the request